# run 32-bit task manager in windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, task-manager

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070646/generate-dump-file-using-task-manager/4104258#4104258) answer that Windows 7 has two versions of the task manager, one being 64-bit and the other being 32-bit.

How do I go about running this 32 bit version of the task manager in Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: The answer is to run the program at `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\TaskMgr.exe`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll find that 64bit windows keeps two copies of system executables. There's c:\windows\system32 for 64bit apps, and "c:\windows\syswow64" for the 32bit versions.

Navigate to the syswow64 folder and look for taskmgr.exe, double click it to run the 32bit version, after task manager opens you will notice "taskmgr.exe*32" in the list, any process in the list with *32 means it is a 32bit version running.

Comment: syswow64 contains the 32bit binaries, has been since XP 64bit. See this page...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us... "What is the SysWOW64 directory?"

Comment: 64-bit in System **32** and 32-bit in SysWOW **64**? Backwards-compatibility can get to be absurd!